# php mysql compare values

Tags: php, mysql, compare

I have an mysql database named gpstracking.
There are a couple tables in this database: positions and devices.

What is the issue.
On the table positions we have a row called device_id.

On the table devices we have a row called id.

On the table devices we have a row called name.

The device_id and id rows are the same id's, they are pointed to get the name.
My problem is, how to in PHP a loop or something to get the name when compare the 2 id rows.

So example:

```
device_id row:
1 
2
3
4
5

id row:

1      Jan
2      Klaas
3      Piet
```

So if i fetch the information from table with the device_id row, i want that the script can get the name from the device_id.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this:

```
Select * from positions
join devices ON positions.device_id = devices.id
```